# How to submit semantic-ui-react Search value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to add submit functionality to my semantic-ui-react Search component but it's not behaving the way i want it to.

The submit should make a ajax call to an api and log out the data.

Does anyone know how to make it work? I'm either getting errors or my ajax request search query ends up empty even if i write something in the input field.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Container, Header, Search } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import './jumbotron.css'


class Jumbotron extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {value: ''}

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    const food = this.state.value;
    const url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${food}&app_id=${appId}&app_key=${apiKey}`

    fetch(url).then( response => response.json())
    .then( data => console.log(data))

    event.preventDefault();
  }


    render() {
        return (
            <Container text>
                <Header>
                    Nutrion
                </Header>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Search
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                type='text'
                value={this.state.value} 
                size='big'
                placeholder=' ...'/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default Jumbotron
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change required here is:-

Instead of

```
<Search
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    type='text'
    value={this.state.value} // THIS CAUSING CONFICT WITH INTERNAL STATE?
    size='big'
    placeholder='What would you like to eat today? ...'/>
```

Should be

```
<Search
    onSearchChange={this.handleChange}
    type='text'
    value={this.state.value} // THIS CAUSING CONFICT WITH INTERNAL STATE?
    size='big'
    placeholder='What would you like to eat today? ...'/>
```

Basically **onChange** should be replaced with **onSearchChange**

Comment: Do you also know how to make it able to submit with pressing enter?

Comment: It should ideally work when you press enter, since you have a type="submit"

Comment: this line inside semantic js search.js file is causing this issue
if (_lib.keyboardKey.getCode(e) !== _lib.keyboardKey.Enter) return;
      e.preventDefault();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145893/discussion-between-user3408151-and-hyrule).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145896/discussion-between-hyrule-and-vivekn).